# Python parse list of dictionaries TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x

I have HTML form input field that returns a list of dictionaries I want to get values from using PYthon in Django View.

The form returns:

```
request.POST['tags'] returns =>  [{"value":"summer"},{"value":"winter"}]
```

When I try interating through it using `[tag['value'] for tag in request.POST['tags']]` to get values, I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

However, if I manually copy the input field results to command line and go line by line it works as expected:

```
>>> test = [{"value":"summer"},{"value":"winter"}]
>>> test
>>> [{'value':'summer'},{'value':'winter'}]
>>> [tag['value'] for tag in test]
>>> ['summer', 'winter']
```

What is happening?

Updated to add print of 3 different request.POST results:

```
request.POST => <QueryDict: {'tags': ['[{"value":"summer"},{"value":"winter"}]']}>

request.POST.values => <bound method MultiValueDict.values of <QueryDict: {
'tags': ['[{"value":"summer"},{"value":"winter"}]']}>>

request.POST[tags] => [{"value":"summer"},{"value":"winter"}]
```

Comment: I would suspect it might have some more levels in between- can you try: ```[tag for tag in request.POST['tags']]``` to double check, if this ```tag``` is really a dict?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski `tag` (or `request.POST['tags']`, or even `request.POST` for what we know) is clearly a string, based on the error

Comment: Then I suspect: ```[eval(tag)['value'] for tag in request.POST['tags']]``` or ```[tag['value'] for tag in eval(request.POST['tags'])] ``` should do?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski never use `eval`. `json.loads` should be the fix here (or even better, `request.json()` or a similar solution available in the web framework OP is using)

Comment: Added additional `request.POST` results to question. `[tag['value'] for tag in eval(request.POST['tags'])]` => `['summer', 'winter']`

Comment: and `json.loads(request.POST['tags'])` => `[{'value': 'summer'}, {'value': 'winter'}]` then `[tag['value'] for tag in form_tags]` => `['summer', 'winter']` which is what I needed.

Comment: So to clarify, per DeepSpace comment above, `request.POST['tags']` result is a string / json, so using `json.loads` converts it to Python dictionary which then behaves as expected?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

> `QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`
>
> Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the last value. Raises django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError if the key does not exist. (This is a subclass of Python’s standard KeyError, so you can stick to catching KeyError.)

You will have to user `getlist()` when you have multiple values for the same key:

```
[tag['value'] for tag in request.POST.getlist('tags')]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

> `QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and a default value wasn’t provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.

---

**EDIT**

Okay, I can see the issue now. You are not sending a list to your arg `tags`, you are sending a string that represents a list.

If I am not missing anything else the following should work:

```
import json

tags = json.loads(request.POST['tags'])
[tag.get('value') for tag in tags]
```

Comment: `[tag['value'] for tag in request.POST.getlist('tags')]` also returns error `string indices must be integers`.